Producer-consumer using Dart Futures: is there a way for a Dart 'task' to suspend while waiting for activity on a data structure?
I'm trying to get some idea/intuition about how Dart's async/await work.
Here is a simple Dart program where there is:

a producer function adding strings to pipe (a List<String>).
a consumer function polling pipe every 100ms, removing any strings found.

Both functions have been made to run concurrently as 'tasks on the event loop' by 'futurizing' them (what's the correct word?). I don't care about the actual value reported by the Futures, just that I get two concurrent tasks on the event loop.
Also, there is no need to "synchronize" access to pipe (i.e. make access thread-safe) as there really is only one CPU thread doing all the work. Additionally, the consumer function must call Future.delayed() to yield the CPU so that the producer is able to run at all.
Is there a way to perform waiting on pipe until it is not-empty rather than checking every 100ms? Am I supposed to use a Dart stream for that?
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

final pipe = <String>[];
final rand = Random();

String now() {
  return '${DateTime.now()}';
}

Future producer() async {
  print('Producer starts at ${now()}');
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int delay_ms = 500 + rand.nextInt(3000);
    print('Producer delaying by $delay_ms ms ...');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delay_ms));
    final payload = 'payload $i';
    pipe.add(payload);
    print("Producer produced '$payload' at ${now()}");
  }
  pipe.add('DONE');
  print('Producer ends at ${now()}');
}

Future consumer() async {
  print('Consumer starts at ${now()}');
  String? received;
  while (received != 'DONE') {
    // do nothing for 100ms, giving the producer CPU time
    // --- but is there a better way? ---
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));
    received = null;
    while (pipe.isNotEmpty && received != 'DONE') {
      received = pipe.removeAt(0);
      print("Consumer received '$received' at ${now()}");
    }
  }
  print('Consumer ends at ${now()}');
}


Future<void> main() async {
  print('main(): Starting');

  final Future producerFuture = producer().then((_) {
    print('Producer finished');
  });

  print('main(): Producer is running');

  final Future consumerFuture = consumer().then((_) {
    print('Consumer finished');
  });

  print('main(): Consumer is running');

  final Future commonFuture = Future.wait([producerFuture, consumerFuture]);

  await commonFuture;

  print('main(): Done');
}

An example run might be:
main(): Starting
Producer starts at 2024-05-28 15:39:38.021731
Producer delaying by 2092 ms ...
main(): Producer is running
Consumer starts at 2024-05-28 15:39:38.040345
main(): Consumer is running
Producer produced 'payload 0' at 2024-05-28 15:39:40.125837
Producer delaying by 2526 ms ...
Consumer received 'payload 0' at 2024-05-28 15:39:40.170401
Producer produced 'payload 1' at 2024-05-28 15:39:42.652816
Producer delaying by 2167 ms ...
Consumer received 'payload 1' at 2024-05-28 15:39:42.695814
Producer produced 'payload 2' at 2024-05-28 15:39:44.820820
Producer delaying by 3091 ms ...
Consumer received 'payload 2' at 2024-05-28 15:39:44.917827
Producer produced 'payload 3' at 2024-05-28 15:39:47.912795
Producer delaying by 2285 ms ...
Consumer received 'payload 3' at 2024-05-28 15:39:47.947775
Producer produced 'payload 4' at 2024-05-28 15:39:50.198882
Producer ends at 2024-05-28 15:39:50.199027
Producer finished
Consumer received 'payload 4' at 2024-05-28 15:39:50.271304
Consumer received 'DONE' at 2024-05-28 15:39:50.271424
Consumer ends at 2024-05-28 15:39:50.271494
Consumer finished
main(): Done


Those are all good answers, which one should be given the tickmark?


Is there a way to perform waiting on pipe until it is not-empty rather
than checking every 100ms? Am I supposed to use a Dart stream for
that?

Yes, there is. And you guessed it right, dealing with Stream is a proper way to handle such a functionality.
Instead of "manual checking" every 100ms, consider the pipe a Stream<int> and let it do the job by listening to its changes.
Additionally, let's use a StreamController

A controller with the stream it controls.
This controller allows sending data, error and done events on its stream.
This class can be used to create a simple stream that others can listen on, and to push events to that stream.

Example:
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

final StreamController<String> controller = StreamController<String>();

String now() {
  return '${DateTime.now()}';
}

Future<void> runProducer() async {
  print('Producer starts at ${now()}');
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    final delayMs = 500 + Random().nextInt(3000);
    print('Producer delaying by $delayMs ms ...');
    // Sleeping here will switch execution to the consumer which will
    // then find and process "payload i-1" through the stream 
    // listener
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delayMs));
    final payload = 'payload $i';
    controller.add(payload);
    print("Producer produced '$payload' at ${now()}");
  }

  print('Producer ends at ${now()}');
}

Future<void> runConsumer() async {
  print('Consumer starts at ${now()}');
  controller.stream.listen((String received) {
    print("Consumer received '$received' at ${now()}");
  }, onDone: () {
    print('Consumer ends at ${now()}');
  });
}

Main:
void main() async {
  print('main(): Starting');

  final Future commonFuture = Future.wait([runProducer(), runConsumer()]);
  await commonFuture;

  print('main(): Done');
}

Btw, make sure to close the StreamController when it is no longer needed to free up resources and avoid memory leaks:
controller.close();


Streams are well suited for performing exactly the task you are describing. It is easy to adapt the function producer to return a Stream<String>:
Stream<String> streamProducer() async* {
  print('Stream starts at ${now()}');
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int delay_ms = 500 + rand.nextInt(3000);
    print('Stream delaying by $delay_ms ms ...');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delay_ms));
    final payload = 'payload $i';
    yield payload;
  }
  print('Stream ends at ${now()}');
}

Notice the keyword yield (instead of return) and the asterisk after async.
In your function main you would then have for example:
final stream = streamProducer();
stream.listen(print);


And a sample console output is listed below:
$ dart bin/stream_example.dart 
main(): Starting
Stream starts at 2024-05-28 17:25:09.912208
Stream delaying by 1679 ms ...
payload 0
Stream delaying by 1766 ms ...
payload 1
Stream delaying by 893 ms ...
payload 2
Stream delaying by 1574 ms ...
payload 3
Stream delaying by 1281 ms ...
payload 4
Stream ends at 2024-05-28 17:25:17.139823

For more details see Creating Streams in Dart.

Nice. Basically, the print function is registered via stream.listen() as callback to be invoked whenever the stream produces another item.

A Future is for producing a single asynchronous value, a Stream is for producing a sequence of asynchronous values.
Here is what the code might look like if converted to using streams.
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

final rand = Random();

String now() {
  return '${DateTime.now()}';
}

// Use async* rather than async for a Stream of data.
// Nothing of the "stream function", not even the first print(),
// is executed before the consumer starts listening for data on 
// the Stream in the "await for".

Stream<String> producer() async* {
  print('Producer starts at ${now()}');
  for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    int delay_ms = 500 + rand.nextInt(3000);
    print('Producer delaying by $delay_ms ms ...');
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: delay_ms));
    final payload = 'payload $i';
    print("Producer produces '$payload' at ${now()}");
    yield payload; // use yield keyword to produce a value in the stream
  }
  // There is no longer a need to signal "DONE", the stream
  // will close if this function ends.
  print('Producer ends at ${now()}');
}

// accept the stream as an argument
Future<void> consumer(Stream<String> stream) async {
  print('Consumer starts at ${now()}');
  // You can use await-for on a steam to await until the next
  // value is produced in the stream (no longer need to wait 100 ms).
  // The event loop switches to running the producer code whenever 
  // the "await for" is traversed.
  await for (final String received in stream) {
    print("Consumer received '$received' at ${now()}");
    // If one sleeps here, neither the producer nor the consumer
    // will do anything until the sleep is over:
    /// await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 20));
  }
  print('Consumer ends at ${now()}');
}

Future<void> main() async {
  print('main(): Starting');
  await consumer(producer());
  print('main(): Done');
}

See also:

https://dart.dev/libraries/async/using-streams
https://dart.dev/libraries/async/creating-streams
https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await


Cool. The execution of this code is interesting as the producer gets CPU only when the consumer goes through the await for. If one sleeps after the print in the consumer loop, production is on hold!. There is no need to send the DONE at the end of the stream as the stream is closed when the producer function finishes. I shall allow myself to add a few comments and remove the production of the DONE.
